# Mongoose schema – using an Object instead of an Array for subdocuments

Tags: mongoose, schema, subdocument

I'm using Node(0.10.5)/Mongo(2.4)/Mongoose(3.6) to build a game and I have a Mongoose schema something like this...

```
var GameStateSchema = new Schema(
    {
        buildings: {
            // This object will contain buildings of the same structure, e.g.
            // "1": {name: "cabin", x: 128, y: 0},
            // "2": {name: "lighthouse", x: 192, y: 64}
            // It'll grow to several hundred buildings.
        },
        nextId: 3
    }
);

var BuildingSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: String, x: Number, y: Number
    }
);
```

**What's the best approach to let each building in the `buildings` objects use the `BuildingSchema`?** I really don't want to go down the route of manually validating everything!

*Note: the `buildings` object isn't an array, e.g. `buildings: [BuildingSchema]`, because I hear Mongo performs badly with large arrays (and the order of the buildings isn't important).*

Comment: what do you mean by validating everything? also, you can't define values in your GameStateSchema, the schema contains the types and such, not data.

Comment: By "validating" i mean checking casting and 'schema strict-mode' writing to the database. Not the more elaborate Mongoose validation methods. And god, yes, sorry, i forgot to make the data lines a comment! Editing now.

Comment: Despite your objections, you should be using an array for `buildings` here.  No question.

Comment: Yes, i think you're right Johnny. I'd overlooked the fact that Mongo doesn't have wildcard fieldnames, so you could only find a building by id, e.g. finding all the lighthouses would be a pain. Seems the best solution for a large array is to split it into smaller ones (if it makes sense for your data). Also, Mongo 2.6 has the $position modifier which should speed up working with arrays.

Comment: Urgh, can it be true: searching an array can only return none, one or all of the array's elements (i.e. finding all the lighthouses would be impossible)?! If so, arrays are definitely not the way to go. Next attempt: a huge sharded buildings collection.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, the answer is simple. You can use the same...

```
buildings: [BuildingSchema]
```

notation for objects as well as arrays. For instance, if you add a new building...

```
GameStateSchema.update({$set: {"buildings.1": {name: "cabin", x:128, y: 0}   }})
```

Mongoose will add a new building using the `BuildingSchema`, doing very basic (but vital) validation, e.g. a building can only have a `name`, `x` and `y`.

If you don't create a `buildings` array explicitly before you $set items, it will default to being an object. Bit counter-intuitive but very handy :)

**EDIT – I spoke too soon, turns out accessing `buildings` via a Mongoose model instance only works when it's an array. The question still stands.**